# How to pass the gallery image to another Statefull Screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here is my code:

```
Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      print('Image Path $_image');
    });
  }
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image` returned from `ImagePicker.pickImage(...)` is a `File` object that you can pass around to other widgets, just like you would with any other object. For example, consider this snippet, where `NewPage` takes a `File` image object as a parameter:

```dart
  Future<void> navigateOnImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    Navigator.of(context)
      .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => NewPage(image)));
  }
```

Another option may be to convert the `File` object to a more handy object for your use case, such as a `UInt8List` object, with the `File.readAsBytes` method. Then you can pass that around just like in the example above.

Check out [this flutter.dev article](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) for more info on passing data when navigating.